# What exactly are functions in programming?

Tags: programming-languages

Are conditional statements, loops, and basic maths operators are functions? I learn functions as a "specific action". But, I saw in a video from youtube that a guy called loops and math operators "Functions". Was he right? OR, I have to modify my definition of functions?

Answer (score 1):

The guy in your video is correct (and nearly all other programming languages are deficient in this feature).  Alphard and Seed7 programming languages do a quite fine job of allowing you to write a new syntax for a conditional statement or loop or various not-so-basic mathematics operators in the form of a function.

See sections 9.6 and 9.7 of http://seed7.sourceforge.net/manual/syntax.htm for melding syntax definition in with functions.

The guy in your video is incorrect if he led you to believe that very many more programming languages other than Alphard and Seed7 have this capability to model statements and loops as functions.

The guy in your video is correct if he was speaking of pure mathematics which nearly all programming languages have failed to capture at all or without so much contortion that it is difficult to recognize the abstract concept amongst all the syntactic machinery that is utilized to express the abstract mathematical concept partially via tangential approximations and kludges.

Comment: Many languages have a concept of "iterators" and "iterables", which allow you to customize the behaviour of `for` loops. Same with basic arithmetic, there are many languages that support operation overloading. So I totally don't agree with you that programming languages fail to capture them as functions.

Comment: @nirshahar, “customize” is different than “is”.  Say you are married.  If I customize your marriage with a million-dollar gift to make your life together as a couple financially easier, then I am still not married to your spouse; I merely customized it as something extant that exists out there in the universe without becoming it.  Tweaking & tuning a function by injecting behavior that resembles a statement is not the same as fully becoming a function (except in Seed7, Alphard, & very very few other programming languages). A poor-man's makeshift emulation of something is not the something.

Comment: It is internally implemented using functions. For example, operators are literally functions with a nicer syntax. Internally $a+b$ might be resolved to $add(a,b)$ (which can be further simplified assuming `add` was not overidden). Same with iterators - they are usually implemented as an object with a `next` method, or sometimes implemented as a function that `yields` values

Comment: @nirshahar, you are in more-heat-than-light violent agreement with the portion of my answer that begins “The guy in your video is correct if he was speaking of pure mathematics”.  Please cease & desist your abusiveness of me.

Comment: First of all, I'm sorry if you felt I was being abusive - this was definitely not my intention! Now, to clarify what I meant to explain in the comments - I just wanted to point out that there are strong similarities between the notions, even in other languages (and I consider this as worthwhile for discussion).